# NSArrayController selection not updating with NSTableView binding

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

This has been befuddling me for hours...

I have an object (CuesDoc) with a property `(NSMutableArray *cuesArray)` and some other properties. The `cues` array holds multiple `Cue` objects. There is a property called `(CuesDoc*) currentCuesDoc` in my `AppDelegate`.

In IB, I have an `NSArrayController`, which is bound to the `AppDelegate.currentCuesDoc.cuesArray`.

I have a **view-based** `NSTableView` which is bound to the `NSArrayController` and can add/remove/edit values in the table and cuesArray. So far so good.

I have detail fields below that, which are bound to `NSArrayController.selection`, with the model key path set to each property.

When the view first appears, the detail fields populate with the contents of the first item in the table view, however when I select other rows, the detail fields do not update to reflect the current selection.

I added an observer to `selectionIndexes` and `selection` for the `NSArrayController`, and when the view appears, I get called for the `observeValueForKeyPath:` method once, but not after changing selections.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For view-based `NSTableView`s, you must bind the tableView's selection indexes to the array controller key of `selectionIndexes` to keep the view's selection in sync with the controller's selection.  Selection bindings are separate from content bindings. The older, cell-based `NSTableView` APIs did not require this step.

Comment: Bingo! That worked. For some reason I don't remember binding the selection separately other times.

Comment: You don't have to do this for cell based NSTableViews, only for view based NSTableViews.